# Can I extract music from a .dll file?

Tags: windows-7, dll, audio-conversion

There's an old Japanese PC game called EGG MARKET (eggm06c29_20040118.zip) that I want to extract the music from. I have no idea how to play the game itself so I may not be able to just record every track with Audacity.

The zip when extracted contains a just the executable file and a .dll called "eggm_bgm.dll" which I can only presume is the background music that I want. There is also a subfolder with the multiplayer version/matchmaking lobby of the game.

Comment: It’s very unlikely you will be able to extract this musical if it’s an embedded resource of a compiled binary.

Comment: http://ring.u-toyama.ac.jp/archives/pc/freem/old_review/eggm06c29_20040118.zip